# Modifying user.profile using Accounts.onCreateUser for loginWithMeetup

Tags: authentication, meteor, meteor-accounts, meetup

When a user creates an account using the the Meetup login package, I want to get a few more values such as the user's full name and URL to their profile picture then store them in user.profile. Currently, I'm checking if the service is "meetup", performing the following GET request and trying to store it in user.profile.

```
if (service == "meetup") {
        var accessToken = user.services.meetup.accessToken;

        var request = Meteor.http.get('https://api.meetup.com/2/profiles',{
            params : {
                access_token : accessToken
            },
            headers: {"User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"}
        });

        if(result.error){
            throw result.error;
        }

        profile = _.pick(request.results,
            'name',
            'photo_url'
        );

        user.profile = profile;

        return user;

    }
```

However, I'm getting an error when I try to create an account. Note that I am able to create an account if I were to remove the code under `if (service == "meetup")` albeit without the fields I need so I know the problem is in here. How can I obtain the user's full name and profile picture URL and store them under user.profile?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you log in through some external service most of them don't give you username and without this register won't succeed, try addin user.username ~

Comment: Try sbking's suggestion. To my knowledge there is no `Meteor.http.get` (there is only `HTTP.get` ) which is why your code is not working.

Comment: That was one of the problems with the code! I finally got it to work and I posted my code below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. Thank you for the other answers! I did manage to get the code to work. I tried a few different things so I didn't isolate what was causing the problem but I'm sure parts of it were that I was using Meteor.http.get instead of HTTP.get (as @sbking and @fuzzybabybunny suggested) and that I was using /2/profile/ instead of /2/member in the request (Thank you @mlc).

In the end, I decided to use an API key from an empty Meetup account I created instead of an access token like before.

Here is the code:

```
if (service == "meetup") {
        var meetupId = user.services.meetup.id;
        var target = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/member/' + meetupId + '?key=' + MEETUP_API_KEY + '&signed=true';

        var result = HTTP.get(target, {
            params: {
                format: 'json'
            }
        });

        var userProperties = result.data;

        options.profile = {
            'name': userProperties.name,
            'link': userProperties.link,
            'bio': userProperties.bio,
            'picture': userProperties.photo.photo_link,
            'id': meetupId
        };

        user.profile = options.profile;

        return user;

    }
```

The above code doesn't validate the returned data before storing it, which it will in its final form.

I hope this helps anyone with a similar question.

Comment: is there a way to find groups by keywords ?

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to find a way to search for groups with keywords per se, but you can query based on topic (of the group). The catch is that you're only allowed to submit one topic per query. See [here](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/groups/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this (using only the APIs as described on http://docs.meteor.com):

```js
if (service === "meetup") {
    var accessToken = user.services.meetup.accessToken;

    try {
        var result = HTTP.get('https://api.meetup.com/2/profiles',{
            params : {
                access_token : accessToken
            },
            headers: {"User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"}
        });

        check(result.data, Object);

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    var profile = _.pick(result.data,
        'name',
        'photo_url'
    );

    user.profile = profile;
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Meteor-specific parts of your question, but the information you want is probably in the [get member](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/member/#get) API call rather than the profiles API call. You probably want to fetch `https://api.meetup.com/2/member/self` to get information about the currently-authenticated user.

The results of the API call will include the member's name as well as a `photo` object with a URL to the profile photo.