# how to use Meetup API with meteor

Tags: meteor, meetup

I'm trying to query the Meetup API using meteor,i tried a Meteor package.
when i call the function below i get this error.
`API requests must be key-signed,oauth-signed, or accompanied by a key`:

```
 Meteor.methods({
      getGroups:function(){
        Meetup.get('2/events', {
        member_id: 'self',
        status: 'upcoming',
        rsvp: 'yes'
      }, {user: this.userId});
      }

    })
```

I used the accounts-meetup package ,and i auth successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide in your request an access key https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/key/ . Also look here [Modifying user.profile using Accounts.onCreateUser for loginWithMeetup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760064/modifying-user-profile-using-accounts-oncreateuser-for-loginwithmeetup)